# Calculate difference between 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to calculate the difference between 2 input times however im getting a problem with minutes and seconds as im getting decimal format for both when i get the difference. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/8deT5/4/

```
 $(function() {

var dNow = new Date();
var localdate= dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes() + ':' + dNow.getSeconds();
var a = $("#start_hour_sch");
var b = $("#end_hour_sch");
var result = $("#hourdifference");


$( "#houradd" ).on( "click", function() {

    a.val(localdate);

});

$( "#hourend" ).on( "click", function() {

    b.val(localdate);

var diff = new Date("1970-1-1 " + b.val()) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + a.val());

var diffSeconds = diff/1000;
var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds/3600);
var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds%3600)/60;
var SS = Math.floor(diffSeconds%3600)/60;

var formatted = ((HH < 10)?("0" + HH):HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10)?("0" + MM):MM) + ":" + ((SS < 10)?("0" + SS):SS)

    result.val(formatted);

});


});
```

Comment: `localdate` is only assigned once, the difference will always be 0

Comment: momentjs has some great features for date / time comparison and formatting: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 0):

Create a different value for the second date

```
$( "#houradd" ).on( "click", function() {
    var dNow = new Date();
var localdate= dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes() + ':' + dNow.getSeconds(); 
    a.val(localdate);

});

$( "#hourend" ).on( "click", function() {
        var dNow = new Date();
var localdate= dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes() + ':' + dNow.getSeconds();
    b.val(localdate);
```